# How can i wait until a RabbitMQ message has been synced to the other nodes in the cluster?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a three node rabbitmq cluster. 
This is the cluster I am using (not mine) https://github.com/bijukunjummen/docker-rabbitmq-cluster.

I am running into an issue where if I send a large amount of messages to a queue with ha-policy=all, and ungracefully shutdown the server, the messages are not all available on the other nodes.

I think this issue is because the node does not have enough time to propagate the message to the other nodes.

I am seeking a way to know if the client needs to resend the message because the server was terminated before message propagation.

Is this possible in the Java RMQ library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into Publisher Confirms https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html